# Google Speech to text available offline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, offline, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I would like to leverage Google's Speech to text service for a desktop app, but I would like it to be offline. Is this possible?

They have on-prem solutions but can it be offline so no data is sent?
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text#all-features

Comment: As far as it is advertised, it is a cloud service so there is no option for offline usage. however, you might be able to find a Lib to help you https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: this speech to text api is online only, still?

Answer (score 3):

Google's Speech to Text API only works through the cloud, it is not possible to work offline, this is because [Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/) and [Text to Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/) make request using REST or RPC calls.

The [Speech-to-Text On-Prem](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/on-prem) allows you to deploy the Speech to Text API through a container or any GKE cluster, but that doesn't mean you can do it in your local desktop.

Comment: On Android the Google's Speech-To-Text is working offline...

Answer (score 1):

Google Speech-to-text API is available offline only for English in several devices. If You want this API to work for you offline for other languages, you should install that Specific language on you device - otherwise it won't work.

Basically Google Speech Recognition requires internet access to make REST and RPC calls. If you have a working with internet access, it will work on every Language you want. But in offline mode it only works on device-specific language, most probably English.